# Setup cPanel to use MX records defined at domain registrar level (and not local MX records)

Tags: domain-name-system, email, mx-record

I use cPanel (without whm on this account) for a number of domains within the same account. For some of these accounts we are only using the related hosting for website hosting, the email is hosted elsewhere.

The DNS records are set at the domain registrar level with the A record pointing to the dedicated IP for our account and the MX records pointing to the related remote mail server. This works as expected.

The issue is that when emails are sent from other domains that are setup with local email in the same cPanel account it routes the email locally and not to to the remote mail server. I understand that if i manually setup the MX records within cpanel then this will work but I really do not want to do this as it means if they change then they will need to be manually changed at domain level and within cPanel and this will have to be done individually for all domains that use a separate mail server.

I am told by my host that the only way to make this work is to define the MX records at domain/registrar level AND separately in cPanel. But i wanted to check with you guys whether there is any way to get cPanel to just lookup the domain/registrar level MX records so they don't have to be duplicated locally (and will propagate automatically if the MX records are changed at domain/registrar level in the future without having to manually change them in cPanel)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, when you create an account in WHM, it will configure local mail accounts and it will set the local DNS to use the local MX records. However, if you do not wish to rely on the local DNS for the MX records, then you can force WHM to always use a remote mail exchanger.

In WHM, goto: DNS Functions -> Edit DNS Zone -> (select domain name)

At the bottom, you will see something called Email Routing. Set this to Remote Mail Exchanger and then ensure the DNS server is restarted once saved.

Comment: Thanks Jason, that makes a lot of sense! Is it possible to update this setting from within the 'MX Entry' page in cPanel itself as opposed to WHM or does it need to be done in WHM? I can use WHM for some accounts that are VPS/dedicated but I also want to do a similar thing on some shared accounts where I don't have WHM access (just cPanel)? Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Sorry to double post but i just tried changing it to 'remote mail exchanger' in cPanel and this seems to have updated the setting in WHM as well and seems to work correctly which is great! I just wanted to check there is no related issues with setting this from within cPanel instead of directly within WHM? Thanks so much Jason

Comment: There will be no issues with setting this in cPanel as opposed to WHM, it depends what you have access to in cPanel. I forgot you can do it in there, but it is the exact same thing and will not cause any issues.

Comment: No problems, glad it's all working for you! :)